# EF6.0 System.NotSupportedException:DateDiff

Tags: linq, entity-framework, datediff

Can someone tell me this? I just want datediff week.

```
var query = (from x in this.DBContext.Attendance
             where x.UserID == id && x.Type == type &&  
                   SqlFunctions.DateDiff("day", x.Date, DateTime.Now).Value == 0
             select x).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: What database you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DateDiff` call can not be translated to SQL query.
You can try to use `x.Date.Day - DateTime.Now.Day` to achieve same result.

Comment: `DateDiff` is exactly what can be translated into SQL query. Also `DateTime.Day` will not work with Entity Framework

Comment: So,Thank you.What should I do?

Comment: I found it.I should use System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.